# What is the meaning of 庸 in 利之而不庸?

Tags: meaning-in-context, literary-chinese

A random passage from Mencius is:

> 殺之而不怨，利之而不庸，民日遷善而不知為之者

The first two lines have the same structure V1 之而不 V2, wherein V1 is expressing someone doing something to another and V2 how this one reacts to it. 
I think I understand the first line 殺之而不怨: someone kills (some people from a group) and they (the group) don't begrudge it.

As for 利之而不庸 I only understand so far that: someone makes the group benefit from something yet the group 庸, of which I don't know the meaning. The meanings I found in different online dictionaries do not make any sense to me in this context. 庸 is translated as "common, unspecial, mean, low".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[庸](http://www.zdic.net/z/19/xs/5EB8.htm) means `酬谢` (reward) here.

> (10) 酬其功劳 [reward]
>   (11) 又如:庸勋(酬劳有功的人)

[And](http://cy.babihu.com/cy_993146v_1.html),

> 6.酬其功劳。
>   《书·益稷》：“明庶以功，车服以庸。”
>   　孔颖达疏：“赐车服以旌别其人功能事用。”
>   《左传·僖公二十四年》：“庸勳、亲亲、暱近、尊贤，德之大者也。”
>   《孟子·尽心上》：“杀之而不怨，利之而不庸，民日迁善而不知为之者。”

So `利之而不庸` means `benefit them (the civilians), and they won't reward (someone)`.

Comment: like in "person A does sth. good to person B, but person B does not do anything good to Person C " ?

Comment: what book are you using ?

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred [Here](http://www.gushiwen.org/GuShiWen_b7d79e43d8.aspx?WebShieldDRSessionVerify=HppcHgrXCCnAZGzmXHWs)'s one kind of translation, for reference only. `（圣王的百姓）被杀而不怨恨谁，得了好处而不报答谁，一天天趋向于善，却不知道谁使他们这样。`